# How to count for each category in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have the following xaml code that generates the UI. You can see the screenshot. I would like to count the quantity for each plat let's say for my image plat 2 has 5qt and plat 1 has 3qt and plat 3 has 3qt.

[image: Here are x, y and z]

Here is the code that I would like to change instead of x, y and z I would like to have the quantity for each plat.

```
<TextBlock Text="There are x plat1, y plat2 and z plat3"
           Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
```

Here is my full xaml code

```
<Page x:Class="TakeOutUI.GestionCommandes"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:local="using:TakeOutUI"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="#eee">

    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Margin="30,0, 30, 30">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Commandes à préparer"
                           Style="{StaticResource Titre1}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation = "Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="sortBtn"  Content="Date Λ"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click = "OnSortDateClick"/>
                    <CheckBox  x:Name="chkVoirTouts"  Content="Voir tout les commandes"  Click = "OnVoirTouts" />
                    <Button Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Click="Nav_AjoutCommande" />
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="There are x plat1, y plat2 and z plat3"
                           Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
                <ListView x:Name="ListCommandes">
                    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                                    Value="Stretch" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin"
                                    Value="0, 10, 0,0" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#fff" />
                        </Style>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Padding="5,15">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NomCommande}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource Titre3}" />
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="Date :"
                                             FontWeight="Bold" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding DateCommande}" />
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Plats à préparer :"
                                               Style="{StaticResource Titre3}" />

                                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCommande}">
                                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                                                        Value="Stretch" />
                                            </Style>
                                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <FontIcon Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                                              Glyph="&#xF127;" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">
                                                        <Run Text="Qté :"
                                                             FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                        <Run Text="{Binding QuantitePlat}" />
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">
                                                        <Run Text="Plat :"
                                                             FontWeight="Bold" />
                                                        <Run Text="{Binding PlatId}" />
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>


            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Here are my 3 models

Commande

```
public class Commande
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCommande { get; set; }

    public Commande()
    {
        ItemsCommande = new Collection<ItemCommande>();
    }

    public string NomCommande { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCommande { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemCommande> ItemsCommande { get; set; }

}
```

ItemCommande

```
public class ItemCommande
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDetailCommande { get; set; }
    public int QuantitePlat { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Commande")]
    public int CommandeId { get; set; }
    public Commande Commande { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Plat")]
    public int PlatId { get; set; }
    public Plat Plat {
        get; 
        set; 
    }
}
```

and Plat

```
public class Plat
{
    [Key]
    public int IdPlat { get; set; }
    public string NomPlat { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my context

```
public class Contexte : DbContext
{
    private static bool _created = false;
    public Contexte()
    {
        if (!_created)
        {
            _created = true;
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();
            InitialisateurBD.Seed();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Plat>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Commande>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemCommande>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
    {
        optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=TakeOut.db");
    }

    public DbSet<Plat> Plats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Commande> Commandes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemCommande> ItemsCommandes { get; set; }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is this a XAML problem? This seems to be a data model task; i.e. you have some data (maybe from a database), you want to group records by "Plat", summing the "Qte" value associated with each "Plat". This is a basic LINQ operation, with lots of answers on Stack Overflow explaining how to do it. What is it you actually need help with here? Why are you presenting only the XAML, and not the part of the code that actually matters?

Comment: I see thank you @PeterDuniho I will and the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the following code to count the quantity for each plat:

```
int[] results = new int[4];
foreach(var cur in ViewModel)
{
    foreach(var item in cur.ItemsCommande)
    {
        results[item.PlatId] = results[item.PlatId] + item.QuantitePlat;
    }
}

var resultStr = "There are " + results.ElementAt(1).ToString() + " plat1, " + results.ElementAt(2).ToString() + " plat2 and " +
        results.ElementAt(3).ToString() + " plat3";
resultString.Text = resultStr;  // resultString is the TextBlock control
```

The `ViewModel` is used to replace your `Contexte` which contains the data for testing . You need to change the `ViewModel` to adapt your code.